Authorize Curl requests to microservices
I have microservices architecture and want to add authorization and authentication (JWT/Oauth2) for curl/Postman requests.
Microservices running inside docker containers.
I don't want to modify existing services and prefer such schema:


I tried to use oauth2-proxy with keycloak, but it offers sign in by web interface.
This SO question (Microservice Authentication strategy) didn't help me.
Diged in Envoy External Authorization envoy front-proxy example. But it need to add envoy instance for each microservice and have simple auth check.

Questions:

Is there another ready-to-use solution?
Can you suggest direction or technology to continue research?
Or it will be easer to write own auth service, working in pair with reverse-proxy and Auth Provider (Keycloak)


Input data:
oauth2-proxy, keycloak, nginx, one API - service - working together in docker containers.
Authentication by OAuth2.
Solution:
I simulated web logging in by python according to this video Python Requests login and persistent sessions tutorial 
It is more simple than using python requests-oauthlib library or Postman, curl requests.

Postman has support for OAuth flows out-of-box.  Curl is trickier, OAuth kind of by definition includes an interactive back-and-forth in order to get that access token, as well as renewing it.
Here's a good post about using OAuth on the CLI, not really recommending it, this level of complexity really needs a programming language to do well.  PostMan flow however is much more tractable:  https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/oauth-20/
